SFML Graphics - ошибка: Failed to load font "" (failed to create the font face)
Не получается никак открыть шрифт (font) в коде на C++, (использую библиотеку SFML Graphics). Уже всеми способами пытался файл открыть, никак не получается. Пытался разные шрифты скачивать, с разными расширениями (ttf, otf...), пытался путь по разному указывать, запихивал ttf (otf) файлы в папку с проектом, ничего не выходит, вечно выскакивает ошибка
"Failed to load font "" (failed to create the font face)"
Что делать?
Вот кусочек кода
const int Width = 1280;
const int Height = 720;

RenderWindow window(VideoMode(1280, 720), "Integral plot", Style::Titlebar); // создание окна (Style::Default)

Font font; // шрифт

if (!font.loadFromFile("TNR.ttf"))
{
    cout << "Не удалось открыть файл со шрифтом.";
}

Пытался прописать
font.loadFromFile("TNR.ttf")
Но все равно та же ошибка.

текущая рабочая директория. указывайте полный путь к ресурсам. например в командной строке.
